# Insert two associative arrays with foreach loop in codeigniter

Tags: php, for-loop, post, foreach, codeigniter-3

I am trying to insert two arrays (associative) with foreach loop in codeigniter

```php
$senti = $this->input->post('field_id'); 
$options = $this->input->post('field');      
           
$i=0;
foreach( $options as $option and $senti as $sen ) 
{
    $insert_option = array
        (
            'form_id' => $token,
            'name' => $this->db->escape_str($option['name']),
            'fillup_id' => $rand,
            'field_id' => $this->db->escape_str($sen['id'])          
        );  
    $this->db->insert('form_value', $insert_option); 
    $i++;
}
```

But I get error with the above code.
On the other hand if I use `foreach( $options as $option)` then I get the entries for `$option['name']` but not for `$sen['id']`.
Also if this could be done with any other loop I am happy to learn.

Comment: You can not just "extend" the foreach syntax however you like. And it is not really clear what structure your arrays have to begin with, so show an appropriate example of both, please.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to loop through two arrays (`$senti` and `$options`) at the same time with `foreach`.

You have to find a way to merge the two arrays. Below is an example with `while`, but it will skip the values of the longest array. I don't know the data structure you're using so I don't know if that's a problem.

Every iteration `while` checks if the key `$i` exists in the array. When the key exists in both arrays it will progress. With `$i++` the variable is incremented by 1 and the loop can start over again.

```
$senti = $this->input->post('field_id');
$options = $this->input->post('field');

$i = 0;

while(isset($options[$i]) && isset($senti[$i])) {
    $insert_option = array
        (
            'form_id' => $token,
            'name' => $this->db->escape_str($options[$i]['name']),
            'fillup_id' => $rand,
            'field_id' => $this->db->escape_str($senti[$i]['id'])          
        );  
    $this->db->insert('form_value', $insert_option); 
    $i++;
}
```